# Pass by Reference and recursion

Tags: java, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I have the following recursive function prototype:

```
public void calcSim(Type<String> fort, Integer metric)
   Integer metric = 0;
   calcSim(fort, metric);
   System.out.println("metric: " + metric);
}
```

I want to print the value of metric as shown above. However it is always zero. Now, when I print at the end of the function, I do get a valid number.

1. How do I pass by reference or get the equivalent functionality like in C++
2. What all can I do with regards to my parameter passing? (by value, by reference, etc...)

Comment: [Call by Object (Sharing)](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm), please.

Comment: You never change the value of `metric`, so it always prints `0`.

Comment: @pst: thanks for the correction. Comment deleted.

Comment: Have `calcSim` return the result, rather than trying to modify it in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as pass by reference in Java, sorry :(

Your options are either to give the method a return value, or use a mutable wrapper and set the value as you go.  Using AtmoicInteger cause it is in JDK, making your own that doesn't worry about threadsafety would of course be mildly faster.

```
AtomicInteger metric = new AtomicInteger(0);
calcSim(fort, metric);
System.out.println("metric: " + metric.get());
```

Then inside the calcSim set it with `metric.set(int i);`

Answer (score 6):

To get the behavior of pass by reference, you can create a wrapper class, and set the value in that class, eg:

```
class MyWrapper {
    int value;
}
```

Then you can pass a `MyWrapper` to your method and change the value, for example like this:

```
public void calcSim(Type<String> fort, MyWrapper metric)
   metric.value++;
   System.out.println("metric: " + metric.value);
   calcSim(fort, metric);
}
```

Comment: Is it Integer a wrap class for int?

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is wrapper class. Wrapper classes are immutable. So, what you are expecting can't be achieved with `Integer` type.

You may create mutable wrapper class around primitive and update the object to achieve what you want.

Comment: Why is Integer class immutable?

Comment: @Don https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793616/why-are-integers-immutable-in-java

Answer (score 1):

**Two big issues:**

1. You are redefining `metric` with the same name in your method as well. How is program printing anything. It should complain at compilation time.
2. **No defined exit criteria.** Does you program(method) stops?

I think you wanted something as (pseudo code as I don't know what are you doing):

```
 public void calcSim(Type<String> fort, Integer metric)
   if(condtion){
     //print or return
   }else{
      //modify fort or metric so that it exits
      calcSim(fort, metric); //call this with modified value
      System.out.println("metric: " + metric.value);
   }
 }
```