# Object reference in Java differ for various Objects?

Tags: java, object, reference

would like to know the difference on following methods, namely why two identical (identical by its logic) methods do not return the same expected result:

1. Method: create a Map of Character and List of Words:

   ```
    void setMapping(List<String> words) {
      Map<Character, List<String>> wordsByLetter = new HashMap<>();
      for (String word : words) {
        char letter = word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        List<String> ref = wordsByLetter.get(letter);
        if (ref == null) {
          ref = new ArrayList<>();
          wordsByLetter.put(letter, ref);
        }
        ref.add(word);
      }
    }
   ```

   So in this case we make a reference to List of Strings called 'ref' and it will be updated each time we call method 'add' on it.
   Unfortunately, the same approach doesn't work with the second one:

2th Method: count all appearances:

```
void countCategories(List<String> categories) {
  Map<String, Integer> mapper = new HashMap<>();
  for (String category : categories) {
  //need object Integer either to provide reference to it and to check whether it is a null
    Integer counter = mapper.get(category);
    if (counter == null) {
      counter = 0;
      //DOESN'T WORK THE SAME WAY:
      //mapper.put(category, counter);
    }
    counter++;
    mapper.put(category, counter);
  }
}
```

So, my question is, why the second method doesn't work the same way as the first one, namely, why we cannot update counter in the particular Collection through object reference?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to ask.

Comment: The answer was written in details here https://stackoverflow.com/q/22793616/3025545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`counter` is an object of the `Integer` class, which means it is immutable. Therefore you cannot update its value.

`counter++` returns a new `Integer` instance and assigns it to the `counter` variable. Therefore, if you call `mapper.put(category, counter)` before `counter++`, the original object referenced by `counter` is stored in the `HashMap`, and your `counter++` statement has no effect on the contents of the `HashMap`.

That's the reason why the following code doesn't work:

```
Integer counter = mapper.get(category);
if (counter == null) {
  counter = 0;
  mapper.put(category, counter);
}
counter++;
```

And instead, you have to write:

```
Integer counter = mapper.get(category);
if (counter == null) {
  counter = 0;
}
counter++;
mapper.put(category, counter);
```

The first snippet, where you store `ArrayList`s in the `HashMap` is different, since `ArrayList` is mutable, and calling `add` for an `ArrayList` already stored in the `HashMap` mutates that `ArrayList`.

Comment: I didn't get *counter is an object of the Integer class, which means it is immutable*. Also, OP has already written the code, which you suggested.

Comment: The answer was written in details here https://stackoverflow.com/q/22793616/3025545

Comment: @Ravi The OP asked why he has to write different code in the two snippets (i.e. why `mapper.put(category, counter);` can't be inside the if statement in the second snippet).

Comment: @Eran Ohh.. I didn't get that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes from mutability of map's value: `List<String>` is mutable, while `Integer` is immutable.

Your second code snippet can be fixed by adding an `else` as follows:

```
if (counter == null) {
    mapper.put(category, 1);
} else {
    mapper.put(category, counter+1);
}
```

or an equivalent conditional expression with no `if`

```
mapper.put(category, (counter != null ? counter : 0) + 1);
```

Comment: @Kh.Taheri Although your link explains a closely related concept, it is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you for your answer, but I believe, Eran had provided much more precise answer providing explicitly, that "counter++ returns a new Integer instance and assigns it to the counter variable", cause otherwise I would provide an example that doubt the immutability of the object Integer as follows:
Integer counter = null; if (counter == null) { counter = 0; } counter++; System.out.println(counter); //result = 1;